# DropShadow IE filter <input> field caret position bug

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I'm using an IE-only filter dropshadow on a `<div>`, but this affects the caret/text cursor position of input and textarea fields within it.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <input type="text"/>   
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(
    OffX=-8, 
    OffY=-8, 
    Color='#00ff0000', 
    Positive='true');
```

A live example can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/Xg8Lb/2/ (the bug is only visible in IE).

Does anyone have any ideas for a workaround?

edit: The bug is apparent in IE8 and IE9. I have not tried in IE10. A quick try told me IE7 won't even let me type in the fields when dropshadow is applied, but this might just as well be jsfiddle - don't know, and don't care :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the following code to CSS:

```
#box input, #box textarea
{
    position:relative;
}
```

This fixed problem in my case. Please see modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keaukraine/XxBsE/

Comment: This introduces a range of new problems in my design, but it solves the basic problem nicely. Thanks a lot :)